# How to make Op Amp Gain Switch Solid state. (vs jumper)

Tags: operational-amplifier, solid-state-relay, gain, digital-potentiometer

[image: Existing op-amp circuit]
How do I create a low-cost solid-state op-amp gain switch to replace a header and jumper? Header pins and jumpers are expensive parts to place, take up a lot of room and the jumper is a headache to manage in assembly. Also, this is part of a product and a user-selectable jumper represents a UI inconsistency; all the other circuit parameters are set in software.

About the circuit: This is a digitally controlled voltage signal generator used in part of an analog feedback control system. Bandwidth requirements are low (<20kHz).  The basic circuit tests well. Currently a jumper selects the gain of the second-stage amp. The circuit range is normally +/-10V with no jumper and +/-5v when the jumper brings R7 in parallel with R5.

**The jumper goes where U14 is currently shown. How do I replace that Jumper with something solid-state?**

- **Back-to-back small discrete signal MOSFETs?** Don’t all the below
  implement some kind of back-to-back switch tpology for low-resistance
  bi-directional control? Why can't I build one from discrete components? 
  (Because I don't know how. **This is where my design ability/experience breaks
  down**.)
- At first glance an inexpensive 1 channel analog switch (FSA4157)
  seemed like a good fit (U14) until I realized the switched voltage
  range of the inexpensive chips are limited to Vss-Vcc
  (0-5v).
- A digital potentiometer would add variable gain control and eliminate
  R5, R6, R7. Again, it turns out the tiny, inexpensive chips
  (MCP4013) also have similar voltage range limitations.
- A quick search of analog switches and digital potentiometers with
  expanded ranges yields impractical prices.
- Solid state “relays” I’ve found are surprisingly bulky and/or
  expensive (CPC1017N). It appears these typically have an opto-isolators 
  (which I don't need).

*This question has been edited from the original post which was flagged as "off-topic" -- probably because I discuss at length the cost reasons why some design options are already ruled out. I contend there is a very specific design question (which was adequately answered) and that cost considerations are not always the same thing as "shopping recommendations" (which are considered off-topic). In the real world, cost is almost always a principle consideration for making design decisions -- especially with numerous otherwise feasible design options.*

Comment: Jumpers expensive? I guess a few cents could blow the budget for some people.

Comment: I would replace this board and the other which REF+ feeds with a better VCO design or instead of gain (1/3+2/3)*4.096*1.02=4.9 with analog switched gain in 1 stage from DAC with Rail-Rail OA and drop need for more than 5V here

Comment: More expensive than a few cents in hidden burden costs -- jumpers require configuration management and assembly instructions for the jumper after placement. Not to mention real estate requirements or the terrible UI.

Comment: There is no reason why this entire toplogy could not be simplified. The  tolerance stackup is terrible 7x1% No jumper needed with proper design from DAC to out

Comment: @Tony Stewart -- I'm all ears.

Comment: start with specs for input/output range and accuracy for f and/or REF

Comment: @Tony Stewart -- The "other board" receiving the REF+ signal is not under my control.

Comment: no matter, there has to be a system spec, this amounts to adding a bandaid gain switch when you have DAC and precision Vref and every 1% adds up in error tolerance

Comment: is this just supposed to be 0-5 or 0-X? 1% or ?

Comment: Output ranges +/-10v or +/-5v (selectable). It's part of a feedback circuit so overall accuracy isn't terribly important. Really only sensitive to middle value of DAC to reliably generate 0V at REF+

Comment: This question has a very specific problem statement and extremely appropriate for this forum. I can see why this question is flagged as off topic -- to a casual browser. In the real world cost is a primary factor driving most every decision and is the criteria why one design may be considered "good" or "elegant" in the face of many alternatives.  I detailed alternative designs to eliminate options already ruled out -- explain why they are not desirable. I'll try to edit the problem statement but too much editing will make the answers and commonest already posted difficult to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Circuit modified.   sources commoned and R& D added. May well work without R3 - see below.
R3 value not shown but could be 10M or higher if environment allows.
R2 can be lower if desired.
Needs thinking but workable (I believe). It's the sort of circuit that can be made to work entirely reliably but which 'has things to think about along the way'.
The main point of unusualness is that the mode with two gates is "floating". R2 turns both FETs off when no external drive is applied.
My experience has been that applying external drive to the floating gate pair tends to cause them to assume the expected on state BUT there is no definite formal path to get there. Adding R3 allows the gates-node to be ground referenced but to float until driven. Once on, it works as expected.

Note: Almost all circuits are "designable". This one is too - but to be fully formally designed needs a few parts which in practice can be omitted. That does not mean that the end result need be unreliable - just that the factors at work that make it work with fewer parts than may be expected take more thinking about than usual.

---

Place a resistor in parallel with R6 and in series with 2 s 'jellybean" N channel MOSFETS in series opposed connection. ie
D1 ground
S1 S2 connected
G1 G2 connected 
D2 to R6b
Drive G1-G2 via a high = on, ground = off signal.
Note resistor biasing to 'persuade' floating node to be ground referenced.
Diode drive provides high or O/C drive.

Adjust R5 and R6a-R6b values to suit.
If R6 = say 12k then a MOSFET Rdson of 100 milliohms per FET = resistance error of +0.2 Ohm/12k ~= 0.002% - so temperature and device variations "not an issue".

Cost in modest volume manufacturing in China = $US0.01/MOSFET + assembly and PCB area costs.

The circuit utilises the fact that MOSFETs are 2 quadrant devices. Each device is on bidirectionally when gate is positive relative to source regardless of D-S polarity.
Two devices are required in series opposition due to body diodes which otherwise would provide reverse conduction when the FET was off.
For small amplitude signals where V_R6 was << 0.6V one might "get away with" a single MOSFET, but this is an imperfect solution as diodes still conduct (at 'exponentially' lower currents) at lower voltages.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fW2sg2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. This looks exactly like what I want. I can have this mocked-up pretty quick. I'll let you know.

Comment: R. This indeed looks workable. The switched resistor has to be lower- maybe 8.3K to account for the +1 factor (minor nit). I don't think it will work reliably (it might sorta work depending on low input and high threshold voltage) unless you drive the switch with +/- voltage so some level shifting on the control would be required if it's 0/5V or 0/3.3V.

Comment: tl;dr switch R6 rather than R5, lower voltage, and easier as one end is grounded.

Comment: @Neil_UK I am switching R6, because it's easier as one end is grounded. (NVL/NTR?)

Answer (score 3):

You can replace the jumper with an analog switch, however it will add some temperature sensitivity and voltage sensitivity of gain (nonlinearity or distortion depending on how you think of it).

However since you're using LM358s you are not too concerned about either of those, so run the numbers and see if it works for you. There are -thousands- to choose from, including some in SOT-23 packages, however for +/-12V you will not find them all that inexpensive so filter out the ones that can't deal with your voltages. The same really applies to digital pots, as you've found.

You could also consider using a latching telecom style miniature relay, but probably a bit expensive.

A slightly trickier pro-tip way to deal with this would be to divide down the feedback signal so its within a +/-5V range and then deal with it using a dirt-cheap 74HC4053 or similar. This will increase the noise a bit, but since you're using LM358s you're probably not all that worried about performance..

Comment: Any thoughts on back-to-back MOSFET switch made from discreet components?

Comment: @Tedsterr After posting my answer I saw your query re back to back MOSFETS  - which is what my answer covers. 'Ships in the night' :-).

Comment: There is a good couple of sections in the "Art of Electronics" on mosfet switches

Comment: Certainly possible, but when level shifting and gate protection for +/-12 supplies is added, not remotely cost effective. If you needed very low Ron it might be justified, but not when you can get all that with a 10 ohm switch in an sot23 for well under $1. DG series..

Comment: @Tedsterr Spehro notes that my suggestion "has issues". I've made some changes. I think is was workable as was with proper drive. || Spehro: comments welcome.

Comment: Well it simulates perfectly.

Comment: The output of the first stage amp is ~+/-2v -- same at R6. So I don't think level shifting is required. I'm more concerned about gain stability in the second stage -- not so much accuracy. The user "tunes" the system's gain when installed. Even a 100 ohm(1) switch represents <1%. I think this is a winner.

Comment: @Tedsterr Frankly, it looks rather marginal to me without level shifting- it effectively depends on a high Vt to do the level shift, but hope it works out for you.

Comment: UM6K33NTN is my current place holder--low gate threshold. It simulated well with a 2N7002W which, on paper, looks marginal. Cost will be ~ $0.2 more than a jumper in up-front costs. But so worth it.